# How to use Submodules with EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, git-submodules, egit, tortoisegit

The Eclipse Team Provider for Git works but i do not see any changes for submodules when I use synchronize.
I see changes with the diff on the command line and also with tortoise i see the changes.

So, does anyone know ho to use Git and Eclipse in a way that synchronize and commit works with submodules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "[Working with Submodules](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Working_with_Submodules)" section shows the submodules in the Git Repositories view:

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/7/70/Egit-13-submodules-node.png]

From there, you have access to two actions:

> - Selecting the `Update Submodule` action on a submodule will check out the commit referenced in the parent repository's index for that submodule.
>     This command will also perform a merge or rebase if that has been configured in the update field for the selected submodule's configuration section in the parent repository's `.git/config` file.
> - Selecting the `Sync Submodule` action on a submodule will update the remote URL used by the submodule from the current value in the `.gitmodules` file at the root of the working directory of the parent repository.