# How to clone specific branch and push it into another project with all history

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm working on git in order to organize a big project that should contain two different subproject independetly
each project contain 4 brachs that represent the different version of it
what I want to do is to create a git repo and 8 branchs(4+4) so that each branch will contains what the refereced branch should contains

however,the main problem is that I didn't find a way to clone a branch and push it into another git repo.

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just `git fetch <remote_name> <branch_name>`?  Unless you really meant an independent clone per branch `git clone --single-branch --branch <branch> <url>`.  The push would be `git push <remote> <branch>`

Comment: but when i push it says that there is no changes to push

Comment: what I want to do is to extract a branch A from projectRepo B and clone it with it histrory into another git repo C

Comment: i tried to use your commande and i had this error
the source reference specifier refs/heads/master  does not correspond to any reference
error: impossible to push references to <origin>

Comment: So you have two unrelated repos each with 4 branches and you want to merge into a new repo?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories might be your answer instead of what I suggested then.

Answer (score 0):

While I have illustrated how to push a branch from a repository to a separate empty repository in [your next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65510951/6309), you could, once you have separated those sub-projects in their pwn repositories, consider **[submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**.

That would allow for your main project to reference those other repositories as submodules, allowing them to evolve on their own, while being re-grouped in the main repository.

I understand you had an [issue with submodules and Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65391844/how-to-put-two-git-repository-into-one-project-on-sourcesup#comment115612726_65392021), but as I [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32879975/6309), you can update those submodules if Eclipse did not fully initialized them.